# Constexpr Iterator in C++

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, template-meta-programming, constexpr

I am interested in creating a very minimal constexpr container for a personal project. The most important thing I need is a container with true constexpr iterators. They are going to be added to the standard eventually (http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p0858r0.html) but I would like to know how to implement them in current C++.

Let's say I had a data structure like this:

```
template <typename T, unsigned N>
struct array {
  const T data[N];

  template<typename... Args>
  constexpr array(const Args&... args) : data{args...} {
}
  struct array_iterator {
    T const* ptr;

    constexpr array_iterator(const T* ptr) : ptr(ptr) {}

    constexpr void operator++() { ++ptr; }
    constexpr void operator--() { --ptr; }
    constexpr T const& operator* () const { return *ptr; }
    constexpr bool operator==(const array_iterator& rhs) const { return *(*this) == *rhs; }
    constexpr bool operator!=(const array_iterator& rhs) const { return !(*this == rhs); }
  };

  constexpr array_iterator begin() const { return array_iterator(data); }
  constexpr array_iterator end()   const { return array_iterator(data + N); }
};
```

What I need is to be able to actually use the iterators in a constexpr context:

```
constexpr array<int, 3> arr(1, 2, 3);
constexpr auto it = arr.begin();
```

But obviously, since I am messing around with the non-constexpr ptr sub-object, I encounter errors like so:

```
iterator.cpp:46:18: error: constexpr variable 'it' must be initialized by a
      constant expression
  constexpr auto it = arr.begin();
                 ^    ~~~~~~~~~~~
iterator.cpp:46:18: note: pointer to subobject of 'arr' is not a constant
      expression
iterator.cpp:45:27: note: declared here
  constexpr array<int, 3> arr(1, 2, 3);
                          ^
```

So what would be a minimal constexpr iterator for a container like array?

Comment: You just need to make `arr` static: `static constexpr array<int, 3> arr(1, 2, 3);`

Comment: That does work in main! But you unfortunately cannot make a variable static if you are in a constexpr function, which is where I imagine this type of data structure would be most useful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`constexpr` has a few meanings.

It can mean a value which can always be calculated at compile time.  It can mean a function that, given compile time arguments, can generate output that can be calculated at compile time.

You have found that your iterators cannot refer to an automatic storage `constexpr` object.  On the other hand, they can be *invoked* within a `constexpr` function.

```
template <typename T, unsigned N>
struct array {
  const T data[N];

  template<typename... Args>
  constexpr array(const Args&... args) : data{args...} {}

  struct array_iterator {
    T const* ptr;

    constexpr array_iterator(const T* ptr) : ptr(ptr) {}

    constexpr void operator++() { ++ptr; }
    constexpr void operator--() { --ptr; }
    constexpr T const& operator* () const { return *ptr; }
    constexpr bool operator==(const array_iterator& rhs) const { return ptr == rhs.ptr; }
    constexpr bool operator!=(const array_iterator& rhs) const { return !(*this == rhs); }
  };

  constexpr array_iterator begin() const { return array_iterator(data); }
  constexpr array_iterator end()   const { return array_iterator(data + N); }
};

constexpr int sum() {
    int retval = 0;
    constexpr array<int, 3> arr = {1,2,3};
    for (int x : arr)
        retval += x;
    return retval;
}

int main() {
    array<int, sum()> test;
    (void)test;
}
```

your [`operator==`](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3fb76500f5d53d4e) was broken but after fixing it we can call `sum()` in a `constexpr` context, which in turn uses iterators.

Comment: Is there any way to create an iterator that can refer to an automatic storage constexpr object or is that something that would have to require runtime computation?

Comment: @SamG Reference and pointers to objects of automatic storage duration are not `constexpr`.  Consider; could you pass it to a template and use its identiy there?  I mean, you could create iterators that contain a *complete copy* of the array they are iterating over, and measure identity based on identity of the array and position within it.